# How to check & open installed parent app in your device from child app?

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I'have parent & child app in my device.I need to check and open parent app. In my app delegate(when app is launched), I am checking if the app is installed then open parent app otherwise go to app store.

I have tried below code to check if app is installed or not in your device.

I was created URL Types, as given-

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>Parent</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>parentAppBundleid</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I have written following code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions-

```
 func openGoYoApp() {
    let parentapp = "Parent://"
    let parentAppUrl = URL(string: parentapp)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(parentAppUrl! as URL)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.open(parentAppUrl!)

    }
    else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
        print("App not installed")
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "ituneLink")!)
    }

}
```

In the given condition, if is returning true and `UIApplication.shared.open(parentAppUrl!)` is executed but its not opening my parent app.

Answer (score 0):

> The parent app's info plist should have something like this:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLIconFile</key>
        <string>temp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.parent-app</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>parent</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

> and in your parent app AppDelegate, you should handle it from here:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    print("open url: \(options)")

    if let scheme = url.scheme, scheme == "parent" {
        // handle url scheme

        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

> then in your child app:
>   // add this to button action or where ever you want it to trigger the 'open parent app scheme'

```
let urlString = "parent://info-to-pass-to-parent"
if let schemeURL = URL(string: urlString) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(schemeURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(schemeURL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in

            print("open success: \(success)")
        })
    }else{
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
        print("App not installed")
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "ituneLink")!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was followed your code. everything working fine. but i did't go to parent app from child app is open. My parent app available in app store but not child app. I did 't write anything code parent app before as you said, I need to check now ? How to check now ?

Comment: @venkat I updated my answer, I added where you can check if the parent app is installed.